# Rotation of object with minimum area rectangle to -90 or -180 degrees

Tags: opencv

[In the attached image the present status where am struck and the expected is clearly mentioned, this should happen to all images loaded continously in loop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGN59.jpg)I have drawn the minimum Area rectangle for an object, now I want to rotate that object and rectangle to either -90 degrees or -180  degrees for analysis. So, can someone please help me out in rotating object with rectangle ???

Comment: have a look at homography transformations (you'll need translation and rotation) and opencv function warpAffine or warpPerspective

Comment: Please attach sample input image and expected output ?

Comment: @ZdaR I have updated the question with a picture, please check it